# disable close message automatically in PrimeReact

Tags: reactjs, primereact

I'm using **PrimeReact** Message UI element and it automatically closed after a period of time determined by `life` property. How can I disable it to don't close automatically.

Here is the message element in my code:

```
message.current.show({ severity: 'error', content: 'Message Detail' });
```

I changed life property value to something like -1 and others but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a not tidy solution in **PrimeFaces** forum about disabling auto close of **toasts** that is worked for **messages** too.

> https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=66087

set sticky property to true `sticky: true` stops auto close, even though I think it defined for another usage.

```
message.current.show({ sticky: 'true', severity: 'error', content: 'Message Detail' });
```